# Using reflection to get a method; method parameters of interface types aren't found

Tags: java, methods, reflection, interface, subclass

How do I get a method using reflection based on a parameter value when the parameter type is an interface?

In the following case (based on [this example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html)), `newValue` would be a `List<String>` called `foo`. So I would call `addModelProperty("Bar", foo);` But this only works for me if I don't use the interface and only use `LinkedList<String> foo`. How do I use an interface for `newValue` and get the method from `model` that has an interface as the parameter `addBar(List<String> a0)`?

```java
public class AbstractController {
  private final AbstractModel model;
  public setModel(AbstractModel model) {
    this.model = model;
  }
  protected void addModelProperty(String propertyName, Object newValue) {
    try {
      Method method = getMethod(model.getClass(), "add" + propertyName, newValue);
      method.invoke(model, newValue);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    } catch (Exception e) {}
  }
  private Method getMethod(Class clazz, String name, Object parameter) {
    return clazz.getMethod(name, parameter.getClass());
  }
}

public class AbstractModel {
  protected PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport;
  protected void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(propertyName, oldValue, newValue);
  }
}

public class Model extends AbstractModel {
  public void addList(List<String> list) {
    this.list.addAll(list);
  }
}

public class Controller extends AbstractController {
  public void addList(List<String> list) {
    addModelProperty(list);
  }
}
```

```java
public void example() {
  Model model = new Model();
  Controller controller = new Controller();
  List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
  list.add("example");
// addList in the model is only found if LinkedList is used everywhere instead of List
  controller.addList(list);
}
```

Comment: why don't you post the code that you have tried and that doesn't work so we can see how you'd like it to work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll actually have to search through all the methods in your model and find those that are compatible with the arguments you have. It is a bit messy, because, in general, there might be more that one.

If you are interested in just public methods, the `getMethods()` method is the easiest to use, because it gives you all accessible methods without walking the class hierarchy.

```
Collection<Method> candidates = new ArrayList<Method>();
String target = "add" + propertyName;
for (Method m : model.getClass().getMethods()) {
  if (target.equals(m.getName())) {
    Class<?>[] params = m.getParameterTypes();
    if (params.length == 1) {
      if (params[0].isInstance(newValue))
        candidates.add(m);
    }
  }
}
/* Now see how many matches you have... if there's exactly one, use it. */
```

Comment: we can't use this for private method

Comment: @HendraWD That’s right. For a private method, you need to use `getDeclaredMethods()` to list methods, and if the method isn’t found, you have to repeat the process on the parent class, and so on.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't mind adding a dependency to Apache Commons, you may use [`MethodUtils.getMatchingAccessibleMethod(Class clazz, String methodName, Class[] parameterTypes)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.html#getAccessibleMethod-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-).

If you mind adding this dependency, you may at least find it useful to take a look at [how this method is implemented](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.java.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12583831/1108305) suggested using Apache Commons to get the `Method` object using `MethodUtils.getMatchingAccessibleMethod`.

However, it looks like you're not using the `Method` object for anything other than immediately invoking it on an instance.  This being the case, you can instead use Apache Commons Lang's [`MethodUtils.invokeMethod(Object object, String methodName, Object... args)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/MethodUtils.html#invokeMethod-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).  Rather than just returning the `Method` object, this instead invokes the method on the given object.

```java
protected void addModelProperty(String propertyName, Object newValue) {
  try {
    MethodUtils.invokeMethod(model, "add" + propertyName, newValue);
  } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
  }
}
```