# How to iterate over a method parameters in an eclipse template?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to create a template in Eclipse for printing a log starting from the method signature in the following way:

```
    void myMethod(Type1 param1, Type2 param2){

         logger.info("myMethod() - [param1: " + param1 + ", param2: " + param2 + "]");

    }
```

I tried to use the `${enclosing_method_arguments}` variable, but I cannot find yet a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using only templates (unless you want to start parsing the generated string).

Take a look at this Eclipse plugin https://github.com/dernasherbrezon/eclipse-log-param. It should be able to produce (something close to) the desired result.

*Note*: haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is what I wanted, but I prefer not to use external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3602544/517134) to try it with [Reflection API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37628/517134)

or maybe you want to change your method to use ellipses(...) as;

```
void myMethod(Object... params){
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        strBuilder.append("myMethod() - [");
        for (int i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
            strBuilder.append("param"+(i+1)+": "+params[i]+",");
        }
        strBuilder.deleteCharAt(strBuilder.length()-1); //last comma deleted
        strBuilder.append("]");
        logger.info(strBuilder.toString());

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best I could do with only Eclipse templates is this:

```
System.out.println("[FINE] ${enclosing_type}.${enclosing_method}(${enclosing_method_arguments}) = " + Stream.of(${enclosing_method_arguments}).map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
```

This creates something like:

```
private void updateRenderScales(double sx, double sy) {
    System.out.println("[FINE] Window.updateRenderScales(sx, sy) = " + Stream.of(sx, sy).map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
}
```